# must be a representative sample to apply factor analysis?

Tags: sample-size, factor-analysis, sample

To apply the exploratory or confirmatory factor analysis, is what we should select a representative sample? And is there any condition to select this sample?
I would validate a translated questionnaires, the first contains 12 items with 3 contrust an the second questionnaire is one-dimentionnal, contains 6 items.

Answer (score 2):

For exploratory factor analysis (EFA), representativeness is not necessary technically, though if you want your results to be representative of a population then the sample must be representative. If you just want to reduce the data, or identify structure among the variables, for the sample you have and not project onto a population (and you won't be running sample statistics on the data or needing to do hypothesis testing), then you can run EFA on any data regardless of the representativeness.

Confirmatory factor analysis (CFA) is kind of a different story. As the name implies, you are confirming that a theoretical structure behind the variables that you have created *prior* to collecting and modeling the data. There is lots of hypothesis testing and model fit checks that go into a CFA. This implies (to me anyways) that we are talking about projecting the relationships found in the sample to a larger population.

That said, in my psychometric work we will run and report CFA statistics on samples that are not necessarily representative, when piloting an instrument. Once we have confirmed (and likely adapted) the structure through a pilot, we will administer the instrument to a larger, hopefully more representative sample, and assess the structure again, also testing for model invariance to make sure the structure is more or less stable across sub-groups.

Regarding your last point, "conditions for selecting a sample", that's a sampling statistics question and I don't think can be answered without a much more detailed context. There are numerous methods for collecting samples and any given one can be appropriate for your study. No single one is best for factor analysis, just as no single one is best for regression or crosstabs. One thing to keep in mind, if you are going to use a complex design requiring weights, you need to find the right software package that can do factor analysis with sampling weights. In R, `survey.lavaan` will do CFA. I'm not aware of any packages that will do EFA with survey weights, though they probably exist and I have just never had occasion to use them.

Comment: I am very grateful for your reply, just I have a question in this way, I would use the factor analysis in the object to measure the construst validity of translate questionnaire. 
My survey is for children in school, Which I understand for your answer, that I can choose any school in my population just for this object!

Comment: In this case, I would use CFA, so you can determine through theory where the items load. Yes, to initially establish construct validity, I would use one school. When you collect data, get one or two additional demographics from the children, that way you can assess invariance. You need to have adequate sample size as well - sample size guidelines unfortunately are dismal for CFA. Can you add these details into your original post, as well as the following: number of items, number of constructs you think you have, scale of the items (binary, ordinal, etc.)